# Joomla 3.7 Change Default Registration Link ID

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

Right now I'm testing a site on local host. But to show the error I'm running into, go to this address:

http://www.bearvalleycomp.com/cust/twoil/index.php/component/users/?view=registration&Itemid=101

What I want it to do is show the page like this:

Edit: I don't have enough rep to post more than 2 links...Enter that same link above without the "&Itemid=101"

But I'm lost in the code to find the address to remove the Itemid=101

I have found a guide where I can edit it through the system menu as shown here:

https://www.templatemonster.com/help/joomla-3-x-edit-registration-page.html#gref

But it appears this 3.x might not be updated for the latest edition.

Any insight would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: I dont see any error on that page.

Comment: There wasn't an error. I didn't want the &Itemid=101 to be at the end of the link because the layout of the home page would overwhelm the area to register. By getting the &Itemid=114 added to the end, it would be a simple registration page without all the graphics.

Answer (score 0):

After looking through multiple files, I did find the answer to change the link. It's located under /modules/mod_login/tmpl/default.php. Down around line 101, I was able to add &Itemid=114 to the end of the index.php?option=com_users&view=registration making it look like this:

index.php?option=com_users&view=registration&Itemid=114

Now when I click on Create an account, I see a page for only registering an account.

However, now I get mail errors but I can look into that later I guess.

Answer (score 0):

To work around this problem you have to add the register page to a hidden menu (normal menu, but willout position module) and use that alias item on your link.
This way you can decide which modules to show or not for that particular page.

Comment: I think this method would work as well if I eventually decide to use a registration page separate from the default login page link.